# How can I avoid an error involving lazy bytestrings?

Tags: haskell

I tried the following code :

```
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Data.Text as T
import Data.ByteString.Builder

it = toLazyByteString $ encodePath (Prelude.map T.pack ["foo","bar"]) [(read "stuff",Nothing)]

main = print it
```

ghci 7.10.3 accepts to give me a type but somehow cannot compute "it" :

```
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

ghc 7.10.3 links but gives :

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong with this expression ? I know it is an ugly expression and that it may look better with OverloadedStrings, but still, I am perplexed.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried using GHC instead of GHCi? What version of GHC are you using? You have given us little information to work with, which makes this question inadequate. Please update it with useful, relevant information.

Comment: @AJFarmar : I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that puzzled me was what type you were `read`ing the string "stuff" to, so I [looked at the types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.12.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html#v:encodePath).

```
encodePath :: [Text] -> Query -> Builder
```

where [Query is an alias for `[(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.12.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Types.html#t:QueryItem). So in this context you are specializing `read` to:

```
read :: String -> ByteString
```

Looking at [the relevant Read instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#line-176), we see:

```
instance Read ByteString where
    readsPrec p str = [ (packChars x, y) | (x, y) <- readsPrec p str ]
```

and

```
packChars :: [Char] -> ByteString
```

So, ByteString just delegates to String for reading, and then packs the result. So your code eventually boils down to:

```
read "stuff" :: String
```

which fails, of course. There's no String that Shows itself as the five characters `stuff`.

Rather, it looks to me like you just want to be using `T.pack` to convert this to a ByteString, just as you do for your other strings.

Comment: Nice. Importing Data.ByteString.Char8 and using pack does the trick.

Comment: NB: `Data.ByteString.Char8.pack` does everything mod 256

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is 'correct' in a strict sense, that is to say it is well-typed, but your problem is what you're computing here:

```
read "stuff"
```

This is actually communicated in the error message:

```
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse"
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- The underlined means the exception is due to the `read` function.
```

(Note that this is not an error – it is an exception, which arises when *running* the program, not when compiling it.)

I don't know what you were trying to construct when you wrote `read "stuff"`, but there's nothing that `"stuff"` can be interpreted as, so it fails to parse.

Examples of valid uses of `read` are: `read "0" :: Int`, `read "True" :: Bool` and so on. `read "stuff"` is meaningless and will naturally cause an exception.

Perhaps you meant `maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a` from `Data.(Lazy.)Text.Read`?

Comment: As you know, there is type inference in Haskell, and encodePath is not polymorphic.

Comment: @Florian This problem has nothing to do with type inference – this is just misuse of a function. What do you mean?

Comment: OK, now I understand what you meant in your answer.